# Cannot ssh to run a remote script using Python

Tags: python, linux, ssh

I have the script below (`test.py` on `1.1.1.1`) to run another remote script on another server (`script.py` on `2.2.2.2`). I have set up the ssh keys so I don't get prompted for password.

```
import subprocess

USER="user"
SERVER_IP="2.2.2.2"
SCRIPT_PATH="/home/abc/script.py"

print ("ssh {0}@{1} '/usr/bin/python {2} aaa bbb'".format(USER, SERVER_IP, SCRIPT_PATH))

rc = subprocess.check_output("ssh {0}@{1} '/usr/bin/python {2} aaa bbb'".format(USER, SERVER_IP, SCRIPT_PATH))
```

`script.py` itself is on `1.2.3.4`, and takes in 2 arguments.

If I copy the command that is printed out in the script, I can execute `script.py` successfully on `1.1.1.1`. But running `test.py` on `1.1.1.1` gives me an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't understand why the script didn't work but the exact same command works on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the additional argument:

```
shell=True
```

Your command will be:

```
rc = subprocess.check_output("ssh {0}@{1} '/usr/bin/python {2} aaa bbb'".format(USER, SERVER_IP, SCRIPT_PATH),shell=True)
```

I assume you need a shell to run a python script.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is to address the need of executing a remote command and not making your script working - then if I could introduce `Paramiko`:

```
import paramiko

ssh_handle = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_handle.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_handle.connect(
    hostname=address,
    port=int(port),
    username=login)

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_handle.exec_command("whoami")
```

IMO it's currently the most "usable" SSH library and works just fine in my projects.